# How to get front camera, back camera and audio with AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession in Objective C for ios sdk < 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, avcam

I tried using code given in [sample of apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), also I tried to run the same sample code but it crashes on same place for on Ipads with ios versions less than 11. The code breaks on the following line

```
NSArray<AVCaptureDeviceType> *deviceTypes = @[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera, AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDualCamera];
```

I tried using either of the device types but it keeps crashing on the same line providing no clue what's happening. I have attached screenshot of the stacktrace 
[image: screenshot 1] [image: screenshot 2].

Similar question is posted but it did not provide an answer for Objective c code and ios versions lower than SDK 11

Comment: you cannot use both front and back cameras at the same time. You also need to make sure that you have permission to use the camera

Comment: @Scriptable I have set permissions in plist file and I don't think I am using front and back at the same time, if so please guide me or give reference tutorial or point out exact line of code which is trying to use both fornt and back camera at the same, besides the code runs fine on iphone with ios 11 in it.